# Existence of deep enough open subgroups in profinite groups

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, infinite-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite profinite group and $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be any family of open subgroups of $G$. Is it possible to choose a family of open subgroups $V_i < U_i$ with the property that, for any finite set of elements $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ and of indices $i_1,\ldots,i_n$, one has that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n g_kV_{i_k}g_k^{-1}$ is a proper subgroup of $\bigcap_{k=1}^n g_kU_{i_k}g_k^{-1}$?

It seems to me that, if we pick each $V_i$ such that the index $(U_i\colon V_i)$ is sufficiently bigger then $(G\colon U_i)$ for each $i \in I$, this should work, but I couldn't find exactly how to do so. I'm also interested in this question when each $U_i$ and each $V_i$ are normal in $G$, and thus simply asking whether we can find such $V_i$ with the property that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n V_{i_k} < \bigcap_{k=1}^n U_{i_k}$.

Comment: I think that one sufficient condition on the indices would be that the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of the indices of the $V_{i_k}$ be bigger than the product of the indices of the $U_{i_k}$, but I'm unsure if this can be enforced under the sole hypothesis that $G$ is an infinite profinite group.

Comment: If $I$ is countable then it is easy to choose the $V_i$ one by one to achieve this.  So if it is not possible in general, it has something to do with the funny combinatorics that can happen with uncountable sets.  (I would not be surprised if you can somehow build a counterexample using something like the $\Delta$-system lemma.)

Comment: Also, note that the version with normal subgroups is equivalent to the original version, since you can always shrink the $U_i$ to be normal (and then you can also shrink the $V_i$ you choose to be normal).

Comment: @EricWofsey I see, so this argument for the countable case also solves the problem for any topologically finitely generated profinite group $G$. Hence, any counter-example would need to come from an infinitely generated $G$. I'm thinking something in the likes of $\prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{F}_p$ or $\prod_{p\text{ prime}} \mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Those still have only countably many open subgroups.  I would expect a counterexample to instead come from something like an uncountable product of copies of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is always possible.  First, as I commented, your question is equivalent to the version with normal subgroups, since any open subgroup contains a normal open subgroup.  So, we will prove only the version with normal subgroups.

Now recursively define a descending sequence of closed sets $C_\alpha\subseteq G$ for ordinals $\alpha$ as follows.  If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, let $C_\alpha=\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}C_\beta$ (for $\alpha=0$ this mean $C_0=G$).  If $\alpha=\beta+1$ is a successor ordinal, define $C_\alpha$ as follows. If $1$ is isolated in $C_\beta$, let $C_\alpha=C_\beta$ if $1$ is isolated in $C_\beta$.  Otherwise, let $C_\alpha$ be a closed neighborhood of $1$ in $C_\beta$ that is not all of $C_\beta$ (so in particular $1$ is not isolated in $C_\alpha$ either).

This descending sequence must eventually stabilize on some set $C_\infty$ in which $1$ is isolated; let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that $C_\alpha=C_\infty$ (which must be a limit ordinal).  Let $N\subseteq G$ be a closed neighborhood of $1$ such that $N\cap C_\infty=\{1\}$ and let $D_\beta=C_\beta\cap N$.  Then $(D_\beta)_{\beta<\alpha}$ is a descending sequence of closed subsets of $G$ such that $\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}D_\beta=\{1\}$ but $D_\beta\neq\{1\}$ for each $\beta<\alpha$.

Now we are finally ready to choose the $V_i$'s.  For each $i\in I$, note that since $\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}D_\beta=\{1\}\subseteq U_i$ and $G\setminus U_i$ is compact, there must exist some $\beta_i<\alpha$ such that $D_{\beta_i}\subseteq U_i$.  Pick a point $x\in D_{\beta_i}\setminus\{1\}$ and let $V_i\subseteq U_i$ be a normal open subgroup that does not contain $x$.

Now I claim that for any $i_1,\dots,i_n\in I$, $\bigcap_{k=1}^n V_{i_k}$ is a proper subgroup of $\bigcap_{k=1}^nU_{i_k}$.  Indeed, let $\beta$ be the maximum of the ordinals $\beta_{i_1},\dots,\beta_{i_n}$.  Then $D_{\beta}\subseteq D_{\beta_{i_k}}\subseteq U_{i_k}$ for each $k$, so $D_\beta\subseteq \bigcap_{k=1}^n U_{i_k}$.  However, if $k$ is such that $\beta_{i_k}=\beta$, then $D_\beta\not\subseteq V_{i_k}$ by construction, and so $D_\beta\not\subseteq \bigcap_{k=1}^n V_{i_k}$.

(To generalize a bit, the same argument should work with $G$ replaced by any compact Hausdorff space, $1$ replaced by some non-isolated point of $G$, and "normal open subgroups" replaced by any neighborhood base at $1$.)

Comment: Thanks! This is a very neat argument. There is one thing that is not clear to me yet.. why does the descending sequence must eventually stabilize? I imagine this must be a consequence of compactness somehow, but $G\setminus \{1\}$ is not compact, so the usual argument of just taking complements don't apply. Or is it somehow bounded by the cardinality of $G$?

Comment: Yeah, it's just about cardinality.  If $\kappa$ is a cardinal greater than $|G|$, then the sequence must stabilize before you reach $C_\kappa$, since at each successor step you remove at least one point from the set and you can't remove $\kappa$ points.